# Как укоротить код с обнулением возвращаемого значения?

Tags: java, любой-язык

Стало интересно, можно ли заменить данный код как то покороче? без использования временной переменной 
Мне нужно по возвращению значения "сбрасывать" его же

```
private static int a;
a = ...;
public static int foo() {
    int t = a;
    a = 0;
    return t;
}
```

Вопрос из разряда "как поменять числа местами без использования мат.операторов"

Comment: Не знаю как сделать то, что вы хотите, но просто выскажусь.

То, что вы сделали нельзя делать. Геттеры должны только возвращать значение, но не менять его. С этим можно получить много проблем в будущем, когда забудете про то, что getTime ещё и обнуляет значение. Разделите на `getTime` и `resetTime` и вопрос отпадет сам собой

Comment: @Виктор, ну тут просто стоит забыть о том что это геттер, я изначально делал без обнуления, и просто забыл изменить имя функции

Comment: Ваш код достаточно прост и короток. Можете здесь посмотреть альтернативы, но они менее понятны: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044769/return-old-value-from-setter-w-o-temp-variable-using-finally

Comment: @Виктор, метод getSet вполне распространённая идеома, сеттер с возвратом последнего значения. Чаще всего однако, необходимо добиваться кросспоточной атомарности этого метода =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не думаю что имеет смысл делать подобные "оптимизации", но можно еще так поизвращаться:

```
public static int foo() {
    try {
        return a;
    } finally {
        a = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Дело скорее и не в смысле, а в умении так вот "поизвращаться", найти нестандартное решение

Answer (score 4):

Ваш код вполне норм, я только рекомендовал бы чуть расширить интерфейс до полноценного `getSet`:

```
private static int v = 0;
public static int getReset() { return getSet(0); }
public static int getSet(int a) { int t = v; v = a; return v; }

public static void main(String args[])
{
    v = 42;

    System.out.printf("%d, %d", getReset(), getReset());
}
```

Однако, если мсье желает извращений, всегда можно выполнить нечто вроде:

```
public static int getReset() { return v + (v=0); }
public static int getSet(int a) { return v + (v=a)-a; } // Могут быть проблемы с переполнением, но могут и не быть, я не уверен :)
```

---

Ну и классическое решение с атомарностью операции:

```
private static final AtomicReference<Integer> v = new AtomicReference<>();
public static int getReset() { return getSet(0); }
public static int getSet(int a) { return v.getAndSet(a); }

public static void main(String args[])
{
    v.set(42);
    System.out.printf("%d, %d", getReset(), getReset());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private static AtomicInteger a = new AtomicInteger(...);
public static int foo() {
    return a.getAndSet(0);
}
```